# Which is the adverbial in this sentence

Tags: adverbials

> You're at the station at the moment, right? OK, so I live about a kilometre from there. Go out of the station and walk down the road and away from the city centre.

For sure there are many adverbials here. But my question is this:

**Is 'about a kilometre from there' the adverbial of place in the second sentence or is it just 'from there' and why?**

Before asking the question, I studied adverbials on BC Learn English website but still can't understand why the adverbial is 'from there' but not 'about a kilometre from there'.

Here's the question, blue ones are the correct answers. [image: question]

Comment: "About a kilometre from there" is a preposition phrase functioning as a locative **complement** of "live". The head of the PP, “about”, has the noun phrase “a kilometre from there” as its object. Within that NP, the PP “from there” modifies the noun "kilometre".

Answer (score -1):

I can see 3 adverbs:

- '**About**', an *adverb of degree*, which modifies the measurement of 'one kilometre' to indicate that it is an approximation.
- '**At the moment**', an adverbial phrase which essentially means the same as the adverb '**now**', an *adverb of time*.
- '**Away**', an *adverb of place*, indicating the relative position to the city centre.